# jQuery response after ajax file upload

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, file-upload

I have a simple form with a file input.
The file upload works fine (I use jQuery ajax & FormData), then in my php code I'm doing some processing and then return a json object.
The problem is that the ajax call always fires the error callback, because of a parseerror, but the json structure is correct.

After some debugging, I notice that in the `responseText` there is the content of uploaded file (xslx), followed by the correct json object created in php page.

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" id="formImport" action="#">
  <div>
    <label for="upload_file" class="label_small">File</label>
    <input id="upload_file" type="file" name="upload_file" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Upload" id="btnUpload" />
</form>
```

And this is the jQuery function:

```
$('#btnUpload').unbind('click').click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($('#formImport')[0]);
  formData.append('extraParam', '123');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'upload.php',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Here the responseText contains the file content before the correct json object
        alert("Error: jqXHR " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + " - textStatus " + JSON.stringify(textStatus) + " - errorThrown " + JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:
The json structure created by php seems to be correct; this is what I see if I print it in log:

```
{
  "ok": "0",
  "multipleMatch": [{
      "row": 22,
      "matches": [{
          "val": "161290348"
      }, {
          "val": "9613464"
      }]
  }, {
      "row": 35,
      "matches": [{
          "val": "395486129"
      }, {
          "val": "32056134"
      }]
  }]
}
```

I can't find any reason why it prepend the file content in the responseText, any idea of why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: If you have unexpected data in `responseText` then it is coming back in the *response* and you need to look at the code which generates the response (and not pay so much attention to the client side code)

Comment: You are right, but from what I see, the json generated by php is right... So, I can't understand from where the other part is coming from. Anyway, I edit the question adding the created json, if can be useful.

Comment: The other part is coming from the PHP. Which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Omg, I just found it! There was an extra var_dump in the php function that looped through xls rows, so obviously it was printed the file data also. Thank you @Quentin! If you add your comment as answer, I'd be glad to mark it, since you pointed me to the right direction :)